# Best option for persisting a string value between pages in Razor CORE

Tags: razor-pages

I want to display the user's name on each page after they log in. Once I've retrieved their name from the database, what's the best way of storing that name in terms of speed and complexity of code?   I've looked at sessions and cookies as options but wondered which is better or if some other way (like persisting a base ViewModel) is recommended.

I just don't want to have to go back to the database each page just to display some simple text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I went with putting all the pretty into cookies and reading them in the `_Layout` page.

Write once, read many and as the values are stored on the end-user's computer so the browser can pick them up locally, rather than from the server in any fashion and if someone hacks the values, it doesn't matter as they're just used for prettification.